# Exporting Wicket to a Web Server

Tags: eclipse, apache, export, wicket

I'm serious when I say have been all over the internet and on google for past few hours trying to find an answer to this question. Ok, I have already coded and compiled a working wicket in Eclipse. It runs in Eclipse just fine but I now need to export this to my webserver. How do I do this!? It's such a simple concept and yet no one has talked about it. I know I need tomcat, but they don't say how to export the files. If a JAR file works. If I need to configure Tomcat is some way. How to get this to work with an already running web apache server. My guess is that tomcat has to be running to execute the java portion of the wicket and then you can just point a link to your index.html. But I have no idea. Enlighten me please with a step-by-step tutorial? I'm a slight beginner with Eclipse and started using Tomcat and Wicket only 2 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Its preferable to pack your project into a war file distribution.

An easy approach to do that, is to use [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) for building it.

For Maven there are plenty of plugins [available](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html), one of them is a ["war" plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/), which helps you creating your war / web archive.

The war file you have simply to put into the webapp of a fresh downloaded tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways but one way is you can compile to a .war file and deploy from the admin console in tomcat. See [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) for the tomcat documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, right click your web application project, select Export -> War File and follow the wizard.

When you have your .war file ready you can then upload it to a Tomcat or Glassfish installation.